# What would cause a live website not to work, when it works from the file system?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML5 and javascript, but I have encountered a problem and I cannot find an answer to it.  Through my testing, the html pages work as I want them to when I am testing them via the file path in google chorme.  When I make the website live, it does not behave the way it should.  This is also in the same web browser that I am testing them in.  The issue comes when I am trying to save data using localStorage.  When I click the button that advances to a new html page and stores this data, nothing happens.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post sample code or your 'live' website so we can see the actual code?

Comment: I would suggest that you query here for "html5 localstorage". Just type those two terms in the search box up at the top there (without the quotes) and I'll bet you get an idea of how to solve your basic problem.

Comment: Where are you posting your file? You said "When I click the button that advances to a new html page" It is a html page? Well I had the same issue like 3 days before.. but I was working with .NET and It was for the size of the file.  I solved it with this tag in the web.config <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="200000"/> but.. It is .NET, hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox + Firebug. It will certainly help you find errors. The NET tab will also tell which resources are loading and which get a 404 error.